# cloud bookmarking app or method working with del.ic.ious/gmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, cloud

There are a lot apps claiming to work with delicious (was recently taken over by AVOS company) on the market. But syncing always fails, I cannot even download the links. Most apps were updated lastly before the AVOS transfer.

Anyone here knowing a working delicious/gmarks app or other apps or browser addons making sending a link directly to delicious/gmarks site possible?

Answer (score 3):

There's an add-on for Dolphin Browser HD which can sync with Google Bookmarks: [Bookmarks to SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.BookmarkPlugin).

[GoMarks for Google Bookmarks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androappsdev.gomarks) is also in Play Store.

Do try [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com) too if you need cloud bookmark sync (not limited to Delicious, Gmarks). It has an Android app as well as Dolphin add-on too. But, its not free on Android.

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Firefox](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) includes support for Firefox Sync, which not only keeps your bookmarks in sync between your mobile device and your desktop Firefox(es), but also supports opening tabs you currently have open in your desktop browsers.

I know this isn't exactly what you were asking for (Del.icio.us/GMarks sync), but it works perfectly and makes any other bookmark syncing site obsolete for me.

Comment: know this, Firefox mobile is also the slowest browser and not really suited for low-specs smartphones. Also dont like the tagging mechanism in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

If your phone supports it, you could upgrade to ICS. The stock browser and (presumably) Chrome beta support syncing to Google.